# What are the rules being used to compute $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\cos x)^{\tan x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

I am given $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln(1-\cos x)}{\cos x} = -1$

So,

$(1-\cos x)^{\tan x} = e^{(\tan x) \ln(1-\cos x)}$

and as $x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$, we have:

$(\tan x)\ln(1-\cos x)= (\sin x)\frac{\ln(1-\cos x)}{\cos x} \rightarrow (1)(-1)=-1$

Therefore,

$\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\cos x )^{\tan x} = \lim \limits_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} e^{(\tan x) \ln(1-\cos x)}=e^{-1} \tag{1}$

I don't quite understand how the last equality in $(1)$ was arrived at.

It seems what the solution is doing is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c}e^x=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c} x} $.

But I thought the rule is:

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c}e^x=e^c$, so I should just substitute $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ into $(\sin x)\frac{\ln(1-\cos x)}{\cos x}$ which will result in a division by 0, so I need to figure out another method.

Am I wrongly understanding and applying the rule to find the limit at a point of an exponential function?

Comment: (1) is done using the continuity of $\exp$, which allows to exchange the limit (i.e. $\lim e^x = e^{\lim x}$). You cannot just plug $x=\pi/2$ in the argument since it is ill-defined (hence you get no information), and the limit is generally "what the function does close to $\pi/2$" (not "what it does exactly at $\pi/2$").

Comment: I've not heard about $\lim e^x = e^{\lim x}$ before. Does it only apply to $e$ or can it be applied to any positive constant?

Comment: Any continuous function $g$ satisfies $g(\lim_{x\to c} x)=\lim_{x\to c} g(x)$.

Comment: Can you please provide me some links that discuss this property in greater detail? I couldn't find any on Google...

Answer (score 1):

such an trick is here not necessary, we get by L'Hospital
$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\frac{\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}}{-\sin(x)}=-1$